# Why do some faces, when cut (knife and loop cut) get group selected as if still one face?

Tags: modeling, faces

[image]

Basically the title. Whenever trying to select this one face, it selects all of them. I have this in several parts of my work.

Comment: are you sure that there is not one big face here?

Comment: The edge may exist, but the face is still connected to the four adjacent vertices.  Select both adjacent faces AND the offending edge, and use Ctrl + F -> Weld edges into faces

Comment: Pretty sure Allen is right. When deleting the face there were still vertices there. i think i figured it out through trial and error.